# Subscribe event Unity VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity share differents assets/script to use VR. I try to develop a simple experience to improve my knowledge of the differents Unity features but I'm in trouble with a call to an event.

In the script MenuButton.cs you can subscribe to an OnButtonSelected event but I don't know how :

MenuButton.cs

```
    public class MenuButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
         public event Action<MenuButton> OnButtonSelected;                   // This event is triggered when the selection of the button has finished.
...

         private IEnumerator ActivateButton()
         {
                // If anything is subscribed to the OnButtonSelected event, call it.
                if (OnButtonSelected != null)
                    OnButtonSelected(this);
         }
    }
```

I try multiple unsuccess way to subscribe this event from another script like :

```
namespace VRStandardAssets.Menu
{
    public class GetDiscover : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private MenuButton m_MenuButton;         // This controls when the selection is complete.

        void OnEnable()
        {
            m_MenuButton.OnButtonSelected += Teleport;
        }


        void OnDisable()
        {
            m_MenuButton.OnButtonSelected -= Teleport;
        }


        void Teleport()
        {
            Debug.Log("Hello");
        }
    }

}
```

But I have the error : "error CS0123: A method or delegate `VRStandardAssets.Menu.GetDiscover.Teleport()' parameters do not match delegate`System.Action(VRStandardAssets.Menu.MenuButton)' parameters".

What does that mean ? I'm just looking for the simplest way to call the event...

I also try with the delegate method but it won't work too... 
Maybe I don't understand well how function the event system Unity and some clear explanation would be welcome even if I already follow some tutorial :

https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system

https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this error is saying is that when you subscribe to the "OnButtonSelected" event, the method you target (in your case, "Teleport") must accept a parameter of type VRStandardAssets.Menu.MenuButton.

This is how the event system tells your listener which button was selected.

So, you could use something like this:

```
void Teleport(VRStandardAssets.Menu.MenuButton buttonPressed)
{
    // if you care which button, access buttonPressed parameter here..
    Debug.Log("Hello");
}
```

(Note: for good programming practice though I would suggest naming this something other than "Teleport" - calling it something like "HandleMenuButton" or "MenuButtonPressed" keeps its intent clear; then inside that method you can call a separate "Teleport" function.  In the future if you need to change the interaction, it will be easier to update the code if you maintain that level of separation.)

Comment: It does the trick thanks !! for sure I will change the naming. Another quick question, my event OnButtonSelected stay null, do you know why ?

Comment: Hmm.. not 100% sure on that -- things to check: make sure you're looking at OnButtonSelected on the same instance of the GetDiscover class.. verify that it's not being unsubscribed somewhere before you test for null.  And last but not least, double-check that you didn't do "= null" instead of "==null" :)